# C# How to add <list>string into Listview

Tags: c#, string, list, listview

i have `List<string>` that contains a parsed output of the netstat command in cmd you see the list is like this :

```
    TCP
0.0.0.0:135
0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
1028
TCP
0.0.0.0:445
0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
4
TCP
0.0.0.0:5040
0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
1328
TCP
0.0.0.0:5357
0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
4
```

I have a listview with 4 columns like this :
[image]

I want to add every 5 lines into a row in the listview so that they match thair columns protocol and so on how can I make that happen?

Comment: I think the question is too general! It does specific the framework or actual required output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            // Cheack to see if the number of items in the list in divisible  by 5
            if (validElements.Count % 5 != 0)
            {
                //keep adding items until the reminder is 0
                while (validElements.Count % 5 != 0) {
                    validElements.Add("na");
                
                }
               
            }

           
          
            // adding the items to the listview
            for (var i = 0; i < validElements.Count; i +=5)
            {

                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(validElements[i]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(validElements[i+1]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(validElements[i+2]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(validElements[i+3]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(validElements[i+4]);
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get always same number of columns then you can use below code.

Like, always you get 5 column.

- TCP
- 0.0.0.0:135
- 0.0.0.0:0
- LISTENING
- 1028

  ```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
   import './index.css';
   import { Table } from 'antd';

   const { Column } = Table;

   const data = [
   'TCP',
   '0.0.0.0:135',
   '0.0.0.0:0',
   'LISTENING',
   '1028',
   'TCP',
   '0.0.0.0:445',
   '0.0.0.0:0',
   'LISTENING',
   '4',
   'TCP',
   '0.0.0.0:5040',
   '0.0.0.0:0',
   'LISTENING',
   '1328',
   'TCP',
   '0.0.0.0:5357',
   '0.0.0.0:0',
   'LISTENING',
   '4'
   ];
   let newData = [];
   let counter = 0;
   let index = 0;

   Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
   if (counter == 0) {
     newData.splice(index, 0, { ...newData[index], Protocol: data[key] });
     counter = 1;
   } else if (counter == 1) {
     newData.splice(index, 0, { ...newData[index], Address1: data[key] });
     newData.splice(index+1, 1);
     counter = 2;
   } else if (counter == 2) {
     newData.splice(index, 0, { ...newData[index], Address2: data[key] });
     newData.splice(index+1, 1);
     counter = 3;
   } else if (counter == 3) {
     newData.splice(index, 0, { ...newData[index], Etat: data[key] });
     newData.splice(index+1, 1);
     counter = 4;
   } else if (counter == 4) {
     newData.splice(index, 0, { ...newData[index], ProcNa: data[key] });
     newData.splice(index+1, 1);
     counter = 0;
     index = index + 1;
   }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
   <Table dataSource={newData}>
     <Column title="Protocol" dataIndex="Protocol" key="Protocol" />
     <Column title="Address1" dataIndex="Address1" key="Address1" />
     <Column title="Address2" dataIndex="Address2" key="Address2" />
     <Column title="Etat" dataIndex="Etat" key="Etat" />
     <Column title="ProcNa" dataIndex="ProcNa" key="ProcNa" />
   </Table>,
   document.getElementById('container')
  );
  ```